# Why is ClosedRange<Int>.contains 3.4 million times slower than expected?

Tags: swift, performance, range

The `contains` method in a `ClosedRange` in Swift seems very slow.

I create the following Swift Playground on macOS for testing:

```swift
import Foundation

func measure(fn: @escaping ()->Void) -> CFAbsoluteTime {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    fn()
    let endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    return endTime - startTime
}

let r1: ClosedRange<Int> = 1222450723...1308640992
let r2: ClosedRange<Int> = 41218238...462709950

let dt_a = measure { let _ = r1.lowerBound <= r2.lowerBound && r1.upperBound >= r2.upperBound }
let dt_b = measure { let _ = r1.contains(r2) }
```

Shouldn't the `contains` method simply do the range comparison I'm doing for `dt_a` in the code above?

- `dt_a` gives me 95 microseconds, whereas
- `dt_b` gives me 326.9 seconds (~5.45 minutes)

That's 3.4 million times slower than expected.

It would seem that it's checking all the values in the range, which doesn't make sense.
Could it be a bug in Swift? Or is this the expected behavior?

I'm using Xcode 15.0.1 (Swift 5)

(*) Note: for context, I found this while solving Part 2 of [2023 Advent of Code Day 5](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/5)

In a real project, Release build with optimizations turned on (`Optimize for speed [-O]`), `dt_b` gave me 356 seconds, worse than in Playgrounds...

Comment: Don't use a Playground when measuring performance, use a regular project (app or cmd line tool) and make sure to test on a release build.

Comment: You should never test performance in a Swift playground as Swift playgrounds are not optimised. Use a real project and compile with optimizations enabled when performing performance-critical tasks or benchmarking performance. `ClosedRange.contains` should be O(1) as it simply checks the upper and lower bounds - [see the source code for ClosedRange.contains](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/ClosedRange.swift#L128), so what you are seeing can only be attributed to measuring in a playground.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the code. I see the inline function, but that doesn't explain the result I'm getting. The actual code is in a real project. I only used Playgrounds so I could share a self-contained example. See the answer from Sweeper [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77606052/1765629)

Comment: The inline function in the `ClosedRange` source code that you pointed at is for a single element, `public func contains(_ element: Bound) -> Bool`. The generic `Bound` refers to an `Int`, whereas I'm passing another `ClosedRange<Int>`. As pointed out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77606052/1765629), the `contains` being used in my case is `contains<C>` where `C` is a `Collection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClosedRange<Int>` conforms to `Collection`, and the `contains` you are calling is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/contains(_:)) method from `Collection`:

```
func contains<C>(_ other: C) -> Bool where C : Collection, Self.Element == C.Element
```

This checks if `self` contains all the elements in `other`. Notice that `other` is an arbitrary `Collection`. This method is not specifically for ranges. `ClosedRange<Int>` uses the default implementation of this method, so there is no special cases for ranges. The default implementation goes through every element of `other` and checks if they are in `self`.

In other words, there is no built-in method specifically for checking whether one range contains another. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64066681/5133585) for other ways of writing such a method yourself.